# Unable to Inline all the buttons to look alike NavBar

Tags: html, css

I actually using four buttons to set as Inline which should cover all the width of the page, but I am facing a problem of getting the fourth button in Same line.

I give them the width of 25% in CSS, because I want them to cover all the page and I have tried all the things but its not working, I removed All the CSS property under my Knowledge

```css
.tabButton {
  width: 25%;
  height: 90%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  float: inline;
}

.buttonForTab button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tabButton:focus,
.tabButton a:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttonForTab m-0 p-0">
  <span><button class="tabButton"><a>Button 1</a></button></span>
  <span><button class="tabButton"><a>Button 2</a></button></span>
  <span><button class="tabButton"><a>Button 3</a></button></span>
  <span><button class="tabButton"><a>Button 4</a></button></span>

</div>
```

I just want to see them all inline, with covering the full width

Answer (score 1):

`float: inline` is an invalid property. it should be `float: left`. for consistency you should add another property, specially if you are not using any framework like bootstrap, `box-sizing: border-box`.
If you want to know more about `float` and `box-sizing` consider reading these great articles.

For `float`: [All About Floats](https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/) and [float | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float)

For `box-sizing`: [Box Sizing](https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/) and [box-sizing | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)

```css
.tabButton {
  width: 25%;
  height: 90%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.buttonForTab button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tabButton:focus,
.tabButton a:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttonForTab m-0 p-0">
  <span><button class="tabButton"><a>Button 1</a></button></span>
  <span><button class="tabButton"><a>Button 2</a></button></span>
  <span><button class="tabButton"><a>Button 3</a></button></span>
  <span><button class="tabButton"><a>Button 4</a></button></span>

</div>
```

another modern and easier way to achieve the same layout is to use flex. To use flex you have to declare the parent's `display` property to `flex`. With flex you can use `width` but its better to use `flex-basis`, which I've used. I've set the `flex-basis` to 24% and then set `justify-content: space-between` to the parent. This will create a nice even space between buttons. If you don't want this then you can remove `justify-content: space-between` and set `flex-basis: 25%`. Also notice I've removed `span` element wrapper from your buttons, which seems unnecessary to me.

To know details about flex read this articles: [A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) and [Basic concepts of flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox)

```css
.buttonForTab {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.tabButton {
  flex-basis: 24%;
  height: 90%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.buttonForTab button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tabButton:focus,
.tabButton a:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttonForTab m-0 p-0">
  <button class="tabButton"><a>Button 1</a></button>
  <button class="tabButton"><a>Button 2</a></button>
  <button class="tabButton"><a>Button 3</a></button>
  <button class="tabButton"><a>Button 4</a></button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use float:left as float:inline is invalid property. 
also give all the properties of button to span so it will go inline as span is a inline element and you are giving 25% width of span which will be 0.
Hope it helps

Comment: it worked bro. But it is showing the fourth button little down

Comment: can you share the screenshot please as i can't see that

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps :)

```css
.tabButton {
  width: 25%;
  height: 90%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  display:inline-block;
      float: left;
      
}

.buttonForTab button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tabButton:focus,
.tabButton a:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="buttonForTab m-0 p-0">
  <span><button class="tabButton"><a>Button 1</a></button></span>
  <span><button class="tabButton"><a>Button 2</a></button></span>
  <span><button class="tabButton"><a>Button 3</a></button></span>
  <span><button class="tabButton"><a>Button 4</a></button></span>

</div>
```

Comment: it worked, but it's showing my fourth button very little down, which is noticeable.. Please help

Comment: @KapilKaushik in snippet its working fine...might be parent class css conflicting..check that correctly..check parent padding it happens much time or wither attch a screenshot or post more code..we need to check your parent class css

Answer (score 0):

```css
buttonForTab span {
  width: 25%;
  height: 90%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 16px;
      float: left;
      display:inline-block;
}

.buttonForTab button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tabButton:focus,
.tabButton a:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttonForTab m-0 p-0">
  <span><button class="tabButton"><a>Button 1</a></button></span>
  <span><button class="tabButton"><a>Button 2</a></button></span>
  <span><button class="tabButton"><a>Button 3</a></button></span>
  <span><button class="tabButton"><a>Button 4</a></button></span>

</div>
```

check this now

Comment: An explanation to what changes you did will greatly add to the quality of the answer